# javainstaller home argument

Tags: java, netbeans

please help. while running the NetBeans 8.2 installer, it says jdk not found on this computer. specify jdk location using "javahome installer argument". i went to the command prompt and ran the installer from there. i gave the address of the installer then --javahome "**the directory of the jdk**" . and it still does not run. please help me. I dont know what to do. I have tried every solution i came across but nothing works. can somebody please explain what is the problem? I have jdk 9.0.1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same, the following worked for me with Apache 12.6

```
Apache-NetBeans-12.6-bin-windows-x64.exe --javahome "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_321"
```

Best of luck note the double hyphens in `JAVA_HOME` and double quotes in JDK location. The Netbeans error screen suggests a single hyphen, but that did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you install JDK (not JRE) on your computer.

Then, open file `{path-to-netbeans}/etc/netbeans.conf` and edit a line `netbeans_jdkhome` to

`netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"`

Comment: There is no netbeans.conf. As soon as I click on the installer it says jdk not found etc etc. Its the first thing it shows when i click on the .exe file i.e the installer setup of netbeans. I've specified the path so Java runs on command prompt. but I want netbeans and it is not Installing.

Comment: That means your PATH variable does not have JDK. Usually, it's something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin`. Follow this up https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 0):

Such self-sure responses, such finality, all apparently basically wrong. (For three years.)

This problem appears to be a finicky demand by a lazy installer programmer. I put the JDK on the E: drive. I got past the problem with:

Apache-NetBeans-12.4-bin-windows-x64.exe --javahome E:\jdk-16.0.1\

(Note the double hyphen, as you apparently knew to do [the installer's error message box shows only -javahome] and note that putting quotes around it failed, but removing the quotes worked.)